# Getting "Hope you enjoy using Facebook tonight" message on Facebook

Tags: facebook

When I logged into Facebook tonight, this was at the top of my wall. Does anyone know why I was presented with this? I asked several friends but none of them saw this on their walls. Nothing happened if you clicked on it and no other text was presented with it.
At the time, when I logged in, I was using Firefox on Arch Linux. I have never seen messages like this before nor am I continuing to see this message.

> We're happy you're here and hope you enjoy Facebook tonight

[image: we're happy you're here and hope you enjoy Facebook tonight]

**UPDATE**
This definitely seems to have something to do with October. I got that one on October 1st and, and today, the last day of October I received another similar one when I logged into my phone.

[image: Good morning, Drew! Thank's for being here.]

Comment: Just want to know you logged in with FB app or from browser? Have you ever get any other message like this, like wishing for some occasion or something else?

Comment: @serenesat, Good points. I have added the requested details to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is *constantly* experimenting with stuff. This is probably just another of their experiments.

There was a lot of talk a few months ago about how Facebook was looking for ways for people to nudge people into posting more positive things to their timelines. I expect this was just something they were trying out. In other words, show this to a few hundred thousand random people and see if what they post that day is more "positive" than people who didn't get the message.

Comment: Do you have any links to the articles talking about this?

Comment: To hand, no. I'd have to dig some up.

Comment: @druciferre: Maybe more than a few months. Here's an article about some of their early attempts, which were a bit ham-handed: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/oct/02/facebook-sorry-secret-psychological-experiment-users . Note that the article says they've modified their guidelines for future experiments, not that they'll stop experimenting. And why should they? Their very existence depends on people wanting to keep coming back to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it now!

It happened when you pressed the **unfollow** button after you click on the **edit** button if you no longer want to follow a friend or a group.

[image: screen shot]

And then you get this note from Facebook.

Comment: I don't think that is the reason behind this note. Around 2 weeks ago I unfollow some of my friend and I never saw this note.